# Scanning DynamoDB with ConditionalOperator set to OR is still performing an AND

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Per the [API Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) I've got the following `scan` params:

```
var params = {
  "TableName": "MyTable",
  "ScanFilter": {
    "id": {
      "AttributeValueList": [
        {
          "S": "ID-A"
        },
        {
          "S": "ID-D"
        }
      ],
      "ComparisonOperator": "IN"
    },
    "facilityName": {
      "AttributeValueList": [
        {
          "S": "Name A"
        }
      ],
      "ComparisonOperator": "IN"
    }
  },
  "ConditionalOperator": "OR"
};
dynamo.scan(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }
});
```

Regardless of the value in the `ConditionalOperator` field, the scan always performs an *AND*. What am I doing wrong?

I would expect with the `OR` to see ID-A, ID-C AND ID-D. I only ever get ID-D.

If I do a plain or scan, with no `ScanFilter` setup this is the data:

```
{
  "Count": 4,
  "ScannedCount": 4,
  "Items": [
    {
      "facilityName": {
        "S": "Name B"
      },
      "id": {
        "S": "ID-A"
      }
    },
    {
      "facilityName": {
        "S": "Name B"
      },
      "id": {
        "S": "ID-B"
      }
    },
    {
      "facilityName": {
        "S": "Name A"
      },
      "id": {
        "S": "ID-C"
      }
    },
    {
      "facilityName": {
        "S": "Name A"
      },
      "id": {
        "S": "ID-D"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: so it is not sdk version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to use the Java SDK to do what you want:

```
public static void test() {
    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest("MyTable");
    scanRequest.setConditionalOperator(ConditionalOperator.OR);

    Map<String, Condition> scanFilter = new HashMap<String, Condition>();

    Condition idFilter = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN).withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue("ID-A"), new AttributeValue("ID-D"));
    Condition facilityNameFilter = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN).withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue("Name A"));

    scanFilter.put("id", idFilter);
    scanFilter.put("facilityName", facilityNameFilter);

    scanRequest.setScanFilter(scanFilter);

    ScanResult scanResult = dynamo.scan(scanRequest);
    for(Map<String, AttributeValue> item : scanResult.getItems()) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }

}
```

I am not familar with the JS SDK that you are using. But your code seems OK. 
When looking at the js [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html), I notcied that ConditionalOperator is introduced in the 2012 version and it is not available in the 2011 version.

Can you verify that you are using the 12 version?